# Loading image in ImageView from OpenLibrary API

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, uri, bitmapfactory

I have written the below program in AsyncTask to load image from internet and show in ImageView. The program works fine if I give any direct image link, but don't work with API links.

What I mean is, for example, [to have the cover of Farmer Boy from OpenLibrary](https://openlibrary.org/dev/docs/api/covers), I need to give below source in html or in browser:
http://covers.openlibrary.org/b/isbn/9780385533225-S.jpg

However, if I enter above link in browser, the browser redirect to below address.
http://ia700804.us.archive.org/zipview.php?zip=/12/items/olcovers4/olcovers4-M.zip&file=49855-M.jpg

My problem is, my code works with last one, but not with the first one.

How can I get the image (in my android application) using the first link?

**CODE:**

```
private class getImageOpenLibrary extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> 
    {
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... args) {
            URL newurl = null;
            try {
                //newurl = new URL("http://covers.openlibrary.org/b/isbn/"+args[0]+"-M.jpg"); // THIS DOES NOT WORK, args[0] = 9780064400039
                newurl = new URL("http://ia700804.us.archive.org/zipview.php?zip=/12/items/olcovers4/olcovers4-M.zip&file=49855-M.jpg"); //THIS WORKS
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Bitmap mIcon_val = null;
            try {
                mIcon_val = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(newurl.openConnection() .getInputStream());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mIcon_val;
        }

        //@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result1) 
        {
            ImageView mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cover);
            mImageView.setImageBitmap(result1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You might wanna consider library like UIL(https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) or Picasso(https://github.com/square/picasso) for such intensive image loading case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should handle the redirection. The url redirects to another URL. You should open a second connection on the redirect URL. To be able to get the redirect URL, set [setInstanceFollowRedirects](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setInstanceFollowRedirects%28boolean%29) to false on the connection and read the `Location` in the header fields.

```
URL url = new URL("http://covers.openlibrary.org/b/isbn/9780385533225-S.jpg");
HttpURLConnection firstConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
firstConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
URL redirectURL = new URL(firstConn.getHeaderField("Location"));
URLConnection redirectConn = redirectURL.openConnection();
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(redirectConn.getInputStream());
```